# Scheduled sms android development

Tags: android, sms

I'm new to the android app development world and looking for a tutorial on scheduling sms to be sent at set times. Or some sample code that anyone has.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) can help you. You can find basic example [here](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/04/02/wake-up-with-the-alarm/)

Comment: Thanks, I think that's going to  do what I need.